# Not able to add image in header as well as in body part of word file using apache poi

Tags: image, apache-poi

I'm adding a picture in the header of a word document. It shows a frame for the image and says "the image cannot currently be displayed". If I add text to the header, it shows the text, and if I add the image in the document body, it also shows the image. So it is getting the image and it shows text on the header, but not the image.

```
    XWPFHeader head = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
       paragraph = head.getParagraphArray(0);
        if (paragraph == null)
            //paragraph = head.createParagraph();
        paragraph=document.createParagraph();   
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("static/Picture.png");
    String imgFile = "static/Picture.png";   
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    
    XWPFPicture picture= run.addPicture(inputStream, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(100),
            Units.toEMU(50));
   
    System.out.println(picture); //XWPFPicture is added
    System.out.println(picture.getPictureData()); //but without access to XWPFPictureData (no blipID)
```

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: What `apache poi` version used? And if `3.14` or `3.15` why using such an old version?

Comment: @AxelRichter I am using apache poi 4.1.1

Comment: Then I cannot reprodúce that issue. Works for me using `apache poi 4.1.1`. Maybe you have a mix of different versions in your classpath? Don't do that. It is not supported.

Comment: @AxelRichter ok thank you for your response....... Is issue with word file or ms office issue??